# FullCalendar 'More' event not display on eventLimitClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

I've use FullCalendar with ajax request for 'allDay' events

and set limit of event as '8' per day in month view  (eventLimit = 8)

Calendar display 'more' button with number of more events

but when 'more' clicked, it doesn't showing any events on the popup

Result of clicking on 'more' is attached below... (https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJw0e.png)

Please help, thank you very much.

[Edit:1 I tried to change allDay = false, but result is also the same ...]

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    editable: true,
    droppable: true,
    dragOpacity: {
        agenda: .5
    },
    selectable: true,
    events: {   
                url: 'xxxx.php',![enter image description here][1]
                type: 'POST',
                error: function(){
                    alert('event fetch error');
                    }
            },
    eventLimit:{
                'agenda': 3, // adjust to 6 only for agendaWeek/agendaDay
                'default': true // give the default value to other views
            }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I solved it by myself

The problem cause of define event(s) as 'allDay' with 'end' date.

Then I remove 'end' date from event's data, it's fine.

Comment: You should probably report that as an issue